# Rigid Motions Reflections

Tags: geometry

How can we prove that any rigid motion can be replicated or is the product of at most 3 reflections, given that a rigid motion is completely determined by the images of any three non-collinear points?

Comment: Given non-collinear $A$, $B$, $C$ and their images $A^\prime$, $B^\prime$, $C^\prime$ ... Show that there's a reflection $p$ such that $p(A) = A^\prime$; and that there's a reflection $q$ such that $q(A^\prime) = A^\prime$ and $q(p(B)) = B^\prime$; and, finally, that there's a motion $r$ ---either a reflection or the identity--- such that $r(A^\prime) = A^\prime$, $r(B^\prime) = B^\prime$, and $r(q(p(C))) = C^\prime$.

Answer (score 1):

A single (or odd number of reflections) changes the orientation of the figure.

A rotation about any point (preserving orientation) can be composed by a pair of reflections, with the degree of rotation equal to double the angle between the two reflection lines.

And a pure translation with no rotation can be accomplished if the reflection lines are parallel.

All rigid motions that preserve orientation can be accomplished with 2 reflection.

And if you need to re-orient, too, you will need a 3rd reflection.